# ArcGIS Server 10.7.1 and QGIS 3.24.1 - Why WFS do not display in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, wfs

I created a WFS Service in ArcGIS Server 10.7.1. This service works ok in ArcGIS Pro and Portal for ArcGIS. However, it does not display in QGIS 3.24.1. Is there any reason? Any setting to adjust in ArcGIS Server and/or QGIS? In QGIS, I can view connection properties...

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: look in the network logs and add what you see to the question

Comment: Check that the GetCapabilities response for the WFS advertises URLS that QGIS can access.

Comment: What version of WFS is supported/requested?  What CRS is used?  Is it a complex feature type?